# Does Gmail send quota warnings via email

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I manage a domain on Google Apps for a lot of heavy email users who mostly use Outlook and rarely login to the Gmail application.

I know there is a quota monitor at the bottom of the page when you login, but can Gmail be setup to send warning emails you you reach 80% or something similar?

That way they know when they should start some housekeeping.

I have searched the Google support pages and have not been able to find anything about emails being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a feature.

However, the current quota and usage is exposed via IMAP and used by some IMAP clients (eg Thunderbird) when you ask it for current quota information. I would have expected this information to be exposed via the Outlook Connector also. Does Outlook have a function somewhere to show the current usage info?

You could also implement something yourself using [IMAP OAUTH](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html) if its really important to you that it sends email. It would be a trivial thing for someone to write a Marketplace app to do the same thing.

Comment: I have implemented a Perl script that gets their usage and quota via IMAP and will email them once they reach 80%.  Waiting a couple days to accept this as the answer for any other suggestions.